# Multi sim GSM modem or alternative

Tags: sms, gsm

I'm trying to administer the SMS trafic of my businesss centrally through a web portal.

In Europe (except UK) we don't have a numbers/SMS trafic provider like Twilio or Clickatell, nor any build in way to administer the SMS traffic for a number via http, so I will have to buy the long numbers and administer the SMS traffic myself.

For this I was looking into a hardware solution for hosting all my SIM cards - I have like 400 sims cards (= numbers). I saw that GSM modems might fit in but they don't seem to scale up very well.

Could you recommend me a GSM modem?
If this is not the best way to approach this, what would my alternatives be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Off topic? - this is related to hardware - more exactly hardware architecture. If anyone else ever confronted with a similar challenge his/her experience would help me.

Answer (score 1):

there was some product from `china`. but i'm not sure if it will work on your country or not.

try checking in this site :

[modem GSM multi sims](http://www.made-in-china.com/showroom/lindamodem/product-detailfoVQbuOYHXcn/China-16-Sim-Cards-Multi-port-Modem-Pool-GSM-GPRS-SimBox.html)

hope it will help you